What is an Alternating Universe Word™?
This puzzle continues the tradition of What is a Word/Phrase puzzles begun by JLee

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Alternating Universe Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.



Alternating Universe Words™
Not Alternating Universe Words™




Activation
Incitement


Cavalry
Squadron


Developer
Builder


Inheritance
Legacy


Lever
Pedal


Lizard
Skin


Motivation
Encouragement


Raspberry
Strawberry


Ray
Beam


Telescope
Spyglass



CSV Version:
Alternating Universe Words™,Not Alternating Universe Words™
Activation,Incitement
Cavalry,Squadron
Developer,Builder
Inheritance,Legacy
Lever,Pedal
Lizard,Skin
Motivation,Encouragement
Raspberry,Strawberry
Ray,Beam
Telescope,Spyglass

